# Single browserstack session for all BDD scenarios

Tags: browserstack, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I want to run all my `BDD` scenarios in one single `browserstack` session, when I run from feature file it is achievable but when it is run from the runner class I am getting new sessions in `Browserstack` for each scenario.

I am using `Serenity-Cucumber` `BDD` framework, used the property
serenity.restart.browser.for.each=NEVER

```
caps.setCapability("reuseSession", true)
caps.setCapability("fullreset", false)
```

Comment: Every new driver instance is considered a new session on BrowserStack.

Comment: I am not closing the driver session in serenity by using any hooks, by default serenity is calling my driver class for the next scenarios in a feature file. As I said if I run the feature file directly using IDE Browserstack just create one session but if I use runner class or maven commands to execute the same feature file then new sessions are created or driver class is been called for each scenario.